# Sonata Seo Bundle in Symfony 4

Tags: sonata, symfony4

I've installed Sonata Seo Bundle in a Symfony 4 project and I have followed the steps from https://sonata-project.org/bundles/seo/2-x/doc/reference/usage.html. But when I launch the application I take this fatal error:

```
The "sonata.seo.page" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the container was compiled. You should either make it public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found just now a solution that work fine the Seo Bundle.

Just, in config/service.yaml file I add:

```
sonata.seo.page:
    class: Sonata\SeoBundle\Seo\SeoPage
```

Previously I have this in the same file:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: true
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is related to the fact that by default, services in Symfony 4 are private. This means that you cannot get them directly from the container using `$container->get('service_id')` unless you explicitly mark them as public in your service configuration at https://chat.openai.com/g/g-U768U2ldM.

Starting from Symfony 3.4, services are private by default. In order to fetch it directly from the service container, you need to define it as public in your services configuration.

Solution 1: Make the service public in `services.yaml`

You can explicitly mark the `sonata.seo.page` service as public in your configuration file:

```
yaml
# config/services.yaml
services:
    sonata.seo.page:
        public: true
```

If the service definition is not you who created but comes from a third-party bundle, you might need to override that service definition to set it as public.